# how can i format the file name like it includes date and time and month and year

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, file, filenames

At the moment I am using to store the  zip  files with the   file name like this...

backup-20111010092345.Zip

but i want to change the file name to this ..`backup-2011-10-10_09:23:45.Zip`

i have got this code ...

```
string zipName = Path.Combine(filepath, string.Format("backup-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")));
string backupFilePath = Path.Combine(filepath, backupName);
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddFile(backupFilePath, "");
    zip.Save(zipName);

  }



string backupName = "backup.sql";
 string filepath = @"C:\Folder\Back\";
```

would any one pls help on this...
many thanks In advance...

**Modified Code:**

```
  string zipName = Path.Combine(filepath, string.Format("backup-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss}.zip", DateTime.Now));
  string backupFilePath = Path.Combine(filepath, backupName);
  using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
  {
    zip.AddFile(backupFilePath, "");
    zip.Save(zipName);

  }
```

Error :Notsupported Exception was unhandled

this is stack trace .

```
     at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CanonicalizePath(String path, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Util.StringExpressionSet.CreateListFromExpressions(String[] str, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission.AddPathList(FileIOPermissionAccess access, AccessControlActions control, String[] pathListOrig, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath, Boolean copyPathList)
   at System.Security.Permissions.FileIOPermission..ctor(FileIOPermissionAccess access, String[] pathList, Boolean checkForDuplicates, Boolean needFullPath)
   at System.IO.File.Move(String sourceFileName, String destFileName)
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save()
   at Ionic.Zip.ZipFile.Save(String fileName)
```

error: The given path's format is not supported.

Comment: Your suggested filename is invalid on Windows, because it contains the ':' character

Comment: @Max: I'd just noticed that myself :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sounds like you've nearly got it (in terms of building the name that you specified) - you just need to change the format string

```
string zipName = Path.Combine(filepath,
    string.Format("backup-{0}.zip",
                  DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss"));
```

You *could* specify that as:

```
string zipName = Path.Combine(filepath,
    string.Format("backup-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH:mm:ss}.zip",
                  DateTime.Now));
```

It's up to you which you find more readable.

Note that this will use the time separator for the current culture. If you *always* want it to be "colon" then you should quote it. On the other hand, is colon even a valid character in Windows filenames? Consider using dash again, or something similar. For example:

```
string zipName = Path.Combine(filepath,
    string.Format("backup-{0:yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm-ss}.zip",
                  DateTime.Now));
```

Comment: got an error at this line  zip.Save(zipName); ERRor: NotsupportedException was unhandled and the given paths format not supported

Comment: @errorcode105 `:` is an invalid file name character. You can't use that in Windows file/directory naming.

Comment: @ChristopherCurrens what about at this colon : at this place  "backup-{0:yyyy   would you pls suggest any solution for this.

Comment: @errorcode105: That's fine - that just says "the rest of the stuff before the close brace is the format specifier".

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to use something other than `:` as it is reserved.  I suggest something like:

```
 DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd_hh-mm-ss");
```

Answer (score 1):

As well as the build in formats, you can get the individual components of a DateTime object using its properties like `myDate.Year` etc. These are detailed on MSDN here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/991wfdee(v=VS.90).aspx

So if you wanted some really odd formatting you could put together a composite string from each component part in whatever pattern you want.