# "The given path's format is not supported" when trying to create file based on current time

Tags: c#, io, filenames, streamwriter

Is there any way to save a file with a variable name?

For example, I have this code but I got error in the `StreamWriter`:

```
string hour = DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss");
string date = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
string filename = "Numbers " + date + " " + hours+ ".txt";
string path = @"C:\ShowMySms\" + filename;

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path, true)) {
    file.WriteLine("test");
}
```

I also tried use

```
using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(@"C:\ShowMySms\" + filename, true))
```

but both ways give me an error.

Is there any way for me to export files with a different using `StreamWriter`?

Thank you in advance!

Edit: the error is

> The given path's format is not supported.

I tried do

```
Path.Combine(path, filename);
```

and put the path in the `StreamWriter` but still getting the same error...

Comment: If you get an error - **please POST** the full and exact error details here! We can't see your screen - nor can we read your mind - you'll need to **provide** those details here, by posting them!

Comment: You can't use colons (`:`) in filenames, which the exception probably already tells you. Replace them with dots, for example.

Comment: I posted the error... you mean the **:** in **"C:\"**?

Comment: Put a breakpoint before where the error occurs and inspect the `path` variable.

Comment: It's true, you cannot use :  O  \ in filename. Try to convert the time and the date using the separator -  .

Comment: @JoãoSilva After a drive letter is one of the few places where `:` are allowed -- `C:\...`. But, they can't be used later in the path for a directory or file's own name -- `.ToString("HH:mm:ss")`.

Comment: the name of path is **"C:\\ShowMySms\\Numbers 18-11-2013 14:52:15.txt"** after the **Path.combine**

Comment: possible duplicate of [how can i format the file name like it includes date and time and month and year](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7742953/how-can-i-format-the-file-name-like-it-includes-date-and-time-and-month-and-year)

Comment: Given my earlier comment _"you can't use colons (`:`) in filenames"_ and your response _"the name of path is [..] 14 **:** 52 **:** 15.txt"_, do you now see the problem?

Comment: I notice now that you are talking about the hours and not in the **"C:\"** Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using this formatting instead:

```
string filename = string.Format("Numbers_yyyyMMdd_HHmmss.txt", date);
```

This will give you file names like

```
Numbers_20131118_155410.txt
```

which contain no "dangerous" and illegal characters (like `:`) in your file name ...

Comment: Just notice now that the **:** that peopla are talking about now is about the time and not in the **"C:\"**... Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

you can also try below code snippet

```
string filename = "Numbers" + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy_HHmmss")+ ".txt";
```

Output:

```
Numbers06-02-2018_122446.txt
```